# Detect if drag is over other element in KonvaJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs, react-konva, konva

Is there a way in KonvaJS to somehow **detect** when the **RED** box is dragged over the **BLUE** box?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-cloud-u5m9x1?file=/src/App.js

```
rect1.on('dragend', (evt) => {
  console.log(evt); // detect if dragging is over the rect2 (blue one)
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Konva has the dragover and drop events. See the official docs example at https://konvajs.org/docs/drag_and_drop/Drop_Events.html